# node.js server is hit multiple times into async function in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs, redux

I'm working with React, MongoDB, node.js and Express and this is my situation:

I have this piece of code inside my component:

```
   renderWishlist(){
      var quantity;
      var itemID;
      var tmp;
      var myData = this.props.currentCart;
      // console.log(myData.length) returns 3
      for (var k=0; k<myData.length; k++){
        tmp = myData[k];
        quantity = tmp.quantity;
        itemID = tmp.itemID;
        this.props.fetchBook(itemID).then(function(book){
          console.log("book: "+JSON.stringify(book));
        });
      }
    }
```

`myData` is an object which holds a bunch of books info.
As you can see from my code above I'm iterating through all these books, retrieving the ID of the book and the available quantity, then I try to get other information (price, pages, etc...) for that particular book from another collection inside the same MongoDB database.
Once this piece of code is running I keep getting multiple logs like this inside chrome console:

```
book: {"type":"fetch_book","payload":{"data":{"_id":"58f6138d734d1d3b89bbbe31","chef":"Heinz von Holzen","title":"A New Approach to Indonesian Cooking","pages":"132","price":23,"image":"IndonesianCooking"},"status":200,"statusText":"OK","headers":{"content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","cache-control":"no-cache"},"config":{"transformRequest":{},"transformResponse":{},"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1,"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"},"method":"get","url":"http://localhost:3001/books/58f6138d734d1d3b89bbbe31"},"request":{}}}
```

Which retrieves correctly the book but it seems to hit the server multiple times for the same book and I don't know why.

For completeness this is `fetchBook` **action creator**:

```
export function fetchBook(id){
  const request = axios.get('http://localhost:3001/books/'+id);
    return {
        type: FETCH_BOOK,
        payload: request
    };
}
```

The reducer:

```
import {FETCH_BOOKS, FETCH_BOOK,FETCH_WISHLIST} from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = { myBooks:[], currentCart:[], currentBook:[] };

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_BOOKS:
      return { ...state, myBooks:action.payload };
    case FETCH_BOOK:
      return { ...state, currentBook:action.payload };
    case FETCH_WISHLIST:
      return { ...state, currentCart: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

My node.js server call:

```
router.get('/books/:id', function(req, res, next){
     Book.findById({_id:req.params.id}).then(function(book){
        res.send(book);
      }).catch(next);
   });
```

Why the server is hit multiple times? If I have, let's say 3 books inside `myData`, I'd expect the server to be hit only 3 times.

Another question I have is: How can I make the `for` loop to wait for `fetchBook` action to finish before going on iterating the next `myData` item?

Comment: Maybe `renderWishlist` was called several times?

Comment: @elmeister  If I do: this.props.fetchBook(itemID).then(function(book){
          console.log("book: "+JSON.stringify(book));
        }); inside the constructor hardcoding the itemID then it is printed only one time in chrome console. btw renderWishlist() is called only one time inside the render() method.

Comment: I would log out two pieces of information here (via `console.log` or `debugger`). The first on the first line of the `renderWishlist(){` definition, to confirm how many times that function is called. The second right around there, logging out `myData.length`. One of those should give you a clue as to what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say `renderWishList` is called from the `render()` method. Your call to `this.props.fetchBook(itemID)` is updating your state, which triggers a re-render, which calls `this.props.fetchBook(itemID)` and ad infinitum it goes. You can put a console.log() at the start of your render() method to confirm this.

I would call `renderWishList()` from your `constructor()` or your `componentDidMount()` method. And I would rename it to something like `createWishList()`, because you are not rendering it with this function, but creating the list which needs to be rendered.

Next, you will want to make sure you are updating your state correctly every time your call to `fetchBook` returns, and then you'll want to use that to render correctly.

**Update State**

I would change the FETCH_BOOKS reducer to:

```
case FETCH_BOOK:
    return { 
        ...state,
        myBooks: [ 
            ...state.myBooks,
            action.payload
        ]
    };
```

This will add the book just fetched to the end of the array of book objects `myBooks`. I am not clear on what is books vs wishlist, so you may want to change the names I've used here. The idea is that when each loop of the for loop is done, your myBooks array in your state has each book that was passed in from `this.props.currentCart`.

Note, I'm not sure, but you may need to execute a dispatch inside the .then of your `this.props.fetchBooks()` call.

**Render with State**

I'm not sure how your are accessing your state, but probably you then want to take your state.myBooks, and map it to create a separate line item, which you can use in your render method. You do this by defining a const like this at the top of your render method:

```
const mappedBooks = state.myBooks.map(book =>
    <div>Title: {book.title}</div>
);
```

You can then use `{mappedBooks}` in the `return()` of your render method where you want a list of the books in myBooks to show on the screen.

**Async For Loop**

Last, I wouldn't worry that you are running each fetchBook asynchronously. In fact, this is good. If you implement it so that each response updates the state, as I've suggested, then that will trigger a re-render each time and your screen will load with each book. Of course with a few books it will happen so fast it won't matter. But this is a very "React-y" way for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out why your server is hit multiple times. But you can use **bluebird** npm for your second question. **reduce** function of bluebird will do exactly what you want.

You can see the documentation here: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.reduce.html

```
renderWishlist() {
    var bluebird = require('bluebird')
    // myData is an array
    var myData = this.props.currentCart;
    bluebird.reduce(myData, function(value, tmp) {
        var quantity = tmp.quantity;
        var itemID = tmp.itemID;
        return this.props.fetchBook(itemID).then(function(book) {
            console.log("book: "+JSON.stringify(book));
        });
    }, 0).then(function() {
        // called when myData is iterated completely
    });
}
```

This code should work for you.